# Angular 2+ Universal page not rendering on server

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, angular8

I have gone through guide provided in docs at angular.io to implement SSR(Angular Universal) in my Angular 8 application, everything went fine, and I have no errors in my server console or browser console, build runs and hosts successfully with the following line

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run
```

**The problem is I see no server side rendered code inside my app-root tag in View Source**

I have already tried stackoverflow questions but found none similar

Here are files:

**server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
// require('jsdom-global')();

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
// const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html'))).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global["branch"] = null;
global["object"] = win.object;
global["HTMLElement"] = win.HTMLElement;
global["navigator"] = win.navigator;

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('./index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClientJsonpModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ServiceWorkerModule, SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { httpInterceptorProviders } from './common/http-interceptor';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { GiftRegistryInfoComponent } from './modals/gift-registry-info/gift-registry-info.component';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { NgReduxModule, NgRedux } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { RootState, rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE } from './redux/app.store';
import { Actions } from './redux/app.actions';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { EventImageUploadComponent } from './modals/event-image-upload/event-image-upload.component';
import { ImageCropperModule } from 'ngx-image-cropper';
import { ShareComponent } from './components/share/share.component';
import { ShareButtonsModule } from '@ngx-share/buttons';
import { ImagesViewerComponent } from './components/images-viewer/images-viewer.component';
import { SlickModule } from 'ngx-slick';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { LoginComponent } from './modals/login/login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ConfirmationComponent } from './modals/confirmation/confirmation.component';
import { PopoverModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/popover';
import { CreateScheduleItemComponent } from './components/schedule/create-schedule-item/create-schedule-item.component';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { AddChecklistItemComponent } from './modals/add-checklist-item/add-checklist-item.component';
import { UpdateBudgetComponent } from './modals/budget/update-budget/update-budget.component';
import { AddExpenceComponent } from './modals/budget/add-expence/add-expence.component';
import { GuestlistItemComponent } from './components/guestlist/guestlist-item/guestlist-item.component';
import { GuestlistInviteComponent } from './modals/guestlist/guestlist-invite/guestlist-invite.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GiftRegistryInfoComponent,
    EventImageUploadComponent,
    ImagesViewerComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ConfirmationComponent,
    AddChecklistItemComponent,
    UpdateBudgetComponent,
    AddExpenceComponent,
    GuestlistInviteComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EventImageUploadComponent,
    ImagesViewerComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AddChecklistItemComponent,
    UpdateBudgetComponent,
    AddExpenceComponent,
    GuestlistInviteComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    GooglePlaceModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyCvKiudJ7QySLw32JNijbiic2HzrXrVZPE'
    }),
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    InfiniteScrollModule,
    NgReduxModule,
    // Always keep all the angular material imports after BrowserModule
    MatSnackBarModule,
    ImageCropperModule,
    HttpClientModule, // (Required) for share counts
    HttpClientJsonpModule, // (Optional) For linkedIn & Tumblr counts
    ShareButtonsModule,
    SlickModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
    TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    httpInterceptorProviders,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    Actions,
    CookieService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    updates: SwUpdate,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    ngRedux: NgRedux<RootState>
  ) {
    updates.available.subscribe(event => {
      const snackBarRef =
        this.snackBar.open('A new version is available, please reload to update', 'Reload', { duration: 0, verticalPosition: 'top' });
      snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    });
    ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "habari-events-pwa": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/css/slick.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/slick.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            },
            "stage": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.stage.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "habari-events-pwa:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "habari-events-pwa:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "habari-events-pwa:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "habari-events-pwa:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "habari-events-pwa:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "src/main.server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": {
                "scripts": false,
                "styles": true
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "habari-events-pwa"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "habari-events-pwa",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "build:dev": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev",
        "build:stage": "ng build --prod --configuration=stage",
        "build:prod": "ng build --prod --configuration=production",
        "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
        "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
        "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
        "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run habari-events-pwa:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
        "@angular-redux/store": "^9.0.0",
        "@angular/animations": "^8.1.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/material": "^8.0.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/pwa": "^0.801.0",
        "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/service-worker": "~8.1.0",
        "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
        "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
        "@ngx-share/button": "^7.1.2",
        "@ngx-share/buttons": "^7.1.2",
        "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jsdom-global": "^3.0.2",
        "jsencrypt": "^3.0.0-rc.1",
        "mock-browser": "^0.92.14",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
        "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.4",
        "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.4.1",
        "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
        "ngx-sharebuttons": "^4.1.4",
        "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
        "ngx-spinner": "^8.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.1.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "ngx-validators": "^5.0.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
      }
    }
```

This is what I am currently getting in View source
[image]

I expect there to be some server-side rendered code inside the app-root tag

Comment: Any error in the terminal server side?

Comment: Nope, not where I am running from the terminal, not in browser console either

Comment: It's _really_ difficult to debug this, since you have so many errant components and dependencies. If you can whittle it down to a minimal reproduction, we can investigate it on the angular/universal repository.